# Is it possible to close a window/tab?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to close a browser window/tab with jQuery/Javascript?

Comment: related: http://www.gtalbot.org/BrowserBugsSection/MSIE6Bugs/ClosingWindowsNotOpenedByJS.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [Close Window in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3670475/close-window-in-javascript)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

window.close();  But this will only close the window opened by the javascript, otherwise a confirm box will appear

Comment: Note that whither a confirmation dialog box appears depends on the browser and with _Chrome 12.0.742.30_ no such dialog box appears.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can close a window

```
window.close();//This will close the window
```

But you will get a confirm box while closing it. If the window in opened using javascript window.open() then you will not see this confirm dialog.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible with the condition that the window/tab was opened via javascript. Otherwise, the user will be presented with a modal confirmation dialog stating that a script is attempting to close the window.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
window.close()
```

but it works only on tabs you opened with javascript
you can't close other tabs by using javascript or jquery