# Trying to close window after alert

Tags: javascript

Ok so I have a page that will post info to the database then it returns to a different page. The only thing is now they want the page to auto close once the alert comes up telling them the database stuff has been saved. I have it on a php page under the conditional if statement and then running javascript from there. The only thing that isnt working it the close. I have tried window.close and self.close and just close() but nothing seems to be working any ideas. Also trying this in Chrome.

```
if( $_POST['finished'] == 'Send' )  
{

(this is just DB stuff here)

echo "<script type='text/javascript'>ConfirmStatus = confirm('Thank you for entering the information.')

if (ConfirmStatus == true) {

self.close();
}</script>";    
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to close a window/tab?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6959122/is-it-possible-to-close-a-window-tab)

Comment: Why force them to confirm a successful update? I would just display the confirmation message on this page, with perhaps a a button to return somewhere.

Comment: That is what I had before but the boss wanted it to just close because the people doing this are not exactly computer savvy so he just wanted me to close the window out on them but if it doesnt work like this I will just switch to a window.location call instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
    if (confirm('Thank you for entering the information.')){
    window.close();
    }</script>";
```

Comment: Are you opening the window with JavaScript window.open()?  If not, you might be able to remove the confirm dialog and just use <script>window.close()</script> and let the browser display the confirm message.