# How to close JSP page from java script

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have created a jsp page. In that jsp page I am using javascript to show error dialog. That error dialog have ok button on clicking on ok button I am closing that dialog using `($( this ).dialog( "close" );` But I want to close the jsp page from where error dialog was called. How to close parent jsp page from javascript?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to close a window/tab?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6959122/is-it-possible-to-close-a-window-tab)

Comment: JSP is a server side technology. It is entirely irrelevant to do anything with browser chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't close a window which you didn't open yourself using javascript.