# how to close and open a window on clicking a button using java script?

Tags: javascript

i wanna close the current window  on clicking a button as well as open a new window using java script .

If this is possible . can any one help me in this .

Thanks in advance .

Comment: Google `javascript open window` and `javascript close window`. Notice however that closing the current window may not be possible if it was not opened by your site

Comment: Search SO before posting a question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6959122/is-it-possible-to-close-a-window-tab
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3670475/close-window-in-javascript

Comment: Please note: Sometimes users uses plugins to block these windows and browsers give you a small hint on the top that you have to confirm to open a new popup-window. Just look, if you have the possibility to open an overlay instead.

Answer (score 3):

It's very simple and it's clearly you haven't even tried to search

```
my_window = window.open("", "mywindow","status=1,width=350,height=150");

if(false == my_window.closed)
      {
         my_window.close ();
      }
      else
      {
         alert('Window already closed!');
      }
```

Read more:

[Window.Open](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.open)
[Window.Close](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.close)