# Can close the browser is running when click button in extjs

Tags: extjs

for example, I'm running page "login.html", on which there are 2 buttons "yes" and "no", you click "no", the browser will automatically close. I hope to get help from people

Comment: Duplicate:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3670475/close-window-in-javascript

Comment: may this help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5455426/is-it-possible-to-close-a-browser-window-using-javascript

Answer (score 1):

Something like the following would work depending on your "input" methods

```
<input type="button" value="close window" onclick="window.close()"/>
```

But just to clarify the close method closes only windows opened by JavaScript using the open method. If you attempt to close any other window a confirm message is displayed, asking the user to choose whether the window is to be closed or not for obvious security reasons

Comment: thank you for looking at my problem, but the problem is I want to shut down the browser if clicking "cancel" on login.
Here is the first part of the code, I want to execute the command to close the browser instead of the "simpleForm.getForm (). Reset ();". So there is no real way:
Code : 
 buttons: [{
            text: 'OK',   
   handler:loginclick
        },{
            text: 'Cancel',
   handler: function () {
         
          simpleForm.getForm().reset();
        }
        }]
 
 });